# Automatically change target language

Tags: google-translate

I almost always use Google Translate for translating English→Hungarian or Hungarian→English.

Selecting "detect language" works well for source language, however I'd like it also to automatically switch target language based on source language and not to translate EN→EN or HU→HU.
(In other words, if source and target language are the same then change target language to a different one used last time.)

Is there a way to do that?

I'm aware of the buttons at the top of text boxes showing last languages, however it's still one click more then I'd like to do.
(I mainly use keyboard, so a solution with a keyboard shortcut may work too.)

## Update

Below pictures shows what I already have:

[image]

as I've already described already I can swap target language by one click, I just want to eliminate that one click.

Answer (score 2):

If you're wanting to switch quickly from Detect→EN to EN→HU, that's similar to what I often do with Dutch and French. I also hate having to open the dropdown and find the language every time, so I've come up with a little trick to shorten the process a bit.

I just type a short word in Dutch (like "goed") which I know will get auto-detected. Then all I have to do is click the Swap Languages button and it goes straight from NL→EN to EN→NL.

For Hungarian, just find a word which does the same. I've tried "pusz" and it works for me. So your flow would be:

1. Type `pusz`
2. Click <kbd>Swap Languages</kbd>
3. Enter whatever you want in English and see the Hungarian translation

Comment: This may not be *exactly* what you wanted, but it's the closest I've been able to find in my frequent usage.

Comment: Thanks for your effort! Unfortunately that workaround is slower than my current process. Please see my update, I hope my description is more clear now.

Answer (score 1):

Another way to speed-up translation is to use Chrome (if use this family of browsers) search keywords, like typing in address bar:

`2hu` <kbd>Tab</kbd>/<kbd>Space</kbd> `some phrase in any language` <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Where `2hu` may be set up as:

> https://translate.google.com/#view=home&op=translate&sl=auto&tl=hu&text=%s

For better explanation you can read [this](https://support.google.com/chrome/answer/95426?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en) short article. Actually it's not very explanatory, but at least it's official.